# Javafx's @FXML fields not being populated in certain cases

Tags: scala, javafx

I have been experiencing a very strange phenomenon when using JavaFX with Scala (I'm *not* using ScalaFX at the moment). It seems that my Controller can correctly wire a `tableView` object:

```
class MainController extends Initializable {
   @FXML private var tableView: TableView[Trade] = null
```

I then have the following initialization code:

```
override def initialize(location: URL, resources: ResourceBundle): Unit = {
  println(tableView)
```

which correctly prints

```
TableView[id=tableView, styleClass=table-view]
```

but now if I add the following code:

```
override def initialize(location: URL, resources: ResourceBundle): Unit = {
  println(tableView)

  val refresher = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new EventHandler[ActionEvent]() {
    override def handle(event: ActionEvent) {
      println("abc")
      println(tableView)
    }}))
}
```

then the original `println()` will print `null` instead. `"abc"` will never be printed.
This seems like black magic. I've been able to consistently observe this behavior.

Any clues why is this happening? It seems to somehow be related with closures, or even Scala. I have yet to try a similar example in Java, but this seems really, really odd.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging and running a decompiler I could figure out what the issue was.

**The issue is probably only going to happen in Scala. 
There's an easy fix for this: always declare your @FXML fields as public and no problem will occur.**

The problem arises when the field is private *and* a closure needs to access this private field. Because for the general case the closure can't access the field as  it is private, the compiler will on your behalf create an object at the class level and will put your field inside it. But that enclosing object will have a strange name and as such Javafx's framework will not be able to correctly populate this field for you!